# Refresh converted model values

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a model (used in a grid), which has a bunch of fields which are calculated from other fields.

Currently I found that calling a convert function on the field is the best approach (I could be wrong). The problem is, that in my grid there are lots of columns which are calculated this way. If a value that effects these fields are changed, then those field will not be recalculated.

According to writing below the way to fix this is to overwrite the set method :
http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2012/02/07/computed-fields-in-extjs-models-via-convert-functions

The problem with this is that there are lots of fields (about 40) which are affected, and the code wouldn't look to good by calling the set on every affected column. Is there a way to refresh the model so everything would be recalculated, or any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I would avoid using the convert() functions this way. You can add your own methods to your models, and use those.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own type of field. This can be done the following way:

```
// define date type that converts to an array
Ext.data.Types.ARRAY = {
    convert: function (value, record) {
        if (!Ext.isArray(value)) {
            return [];
        }
        else {
            return value;
        }
    },
    type: 'array'
};
```

Your field can than use the `{name: 'fieldName', type: 'array'}`